# its really necessary to include the type="text" attribute on html inputs?

Tags: html, input

Does it make any difference if i don´t include this attribute?

For example, on this `<input>`:

```
<input class="trn" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search..." />
```

Comment: Its a good idea to use `type="text"` because even though you may know what type your input is, it will make the code easier to read for others and it doesn't hurt anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text is the default as @Xufox pointed out. Even if you try to validate against a W3C validator, and you type the input without the type, it will mark it as valid. You can try to validate your doc here:

https://validator.w3.org/check

However, as personal preference, and for readability purposes, I would always specify the type.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It's best practice to put `type="whatever"` because that will tell the HTML DOM what kind of input you want. Otherwise how does it know you want a radio button, checkbox, input field?

Comment: But `type="text"` is the _default_, which the DOM _will_ know.

Comment: So, a input cant turn into **anything** (radio, checkbox, date selector...) just by using this attribute?

Comment: @HenriqueHBR you can try it, that is why they have the `type` attribute.

Comment: Think readability, it would much easier to read with the type there for you, and others.

Comment: Adding on, if you expect to be implicit it's a source of bugs to be introduced...